# Check if matching record exists within 28 days of current record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a unique id field, a userid field, and a date field.

What I want to do is have a column which flags if there is a record in the next 28 days with the same userid.

It is only the future i'm looking at, not past records..

```
id | uid | date       | future
1  | 342 | 23/10/2007 | 1
2  | 342 | 3/11/2007  | 0
3  | 342 | 20/2/2009  | 0
4  | 147 | 22/2/2009  | 0
```

This is a basic example of the result i'm after.

I'm using mssql 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query would return the rows matching your requirement.  If you want to, you could create a view from this query so that you could run other queries on just the future rows.

```
SELECT id, uid, date FROM orders current
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * from orders future 
    WHERE future.date < DateAdd(DAYS, 28, current.date)
    AND future.date > getdate()
    AND future.uid = current.uid
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option

```
SELECT id, uid, DATE,
    CASE WHEN MIN(daterange) BETWEEN 0 AND 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
    (
    SELECT m1.id, m1.uid, m1.date, DATEDIFF(DD, m1.date, m2.date) AS daterange
    FROM MyTable m1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable m2 ON m1.uid = m2.uid
        AND m1.id <> m2.id
        AND m1.date <= m2.date
) x
GROUP BY id, uid, DATE
ORDER BY id
```